# Emberjs 1.13.0—Call Action of Component

Tags: ember.js

I have such a Component:

```
App.MyNiceComponent = Ember.component.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function () { … }
  }
});
```

The template for it:

```
<h1>My Nice Component</h1>
{{ yield this }}
```

Anywhere in another template:

```
{{#my-nice as |mn| }}
  …
  <a onclick={{ action 'save' }}>Save</save>
{{/my-nice}}
```

Clicking on the Link make Ember try to trigger the Action in the routes controller. I guess that is because the version we are using here is so old, but is there any way to make ember call the components Action, or to just hand over a function reference to the link, so that this is called?

In another component, which is designed to have certain child components, I could manage to do it like so:

```
App.AChildComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  targetObject: Em.computed.alias('parentView'),
  task: '',
  action: 'onChildClick', //present as Action in the parent Compoent

  click: function(){
    this.sendAction('action', this.get('task'));
  }
})
```

In hbs this would look like that:

```
{{#my-nice}}
  {{#a-child task="do this"}}
{{/my-nice}}
```

In this case I really would love to make ember trigger the compoents actions, without the way over the controller…

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you accept my answer? It will help others

Answer (score 1):

@philipp, you can use action helper to pass the action from component to anywhere(pass `action "actionName"` as another parameter in yield). For eg:- In your case `<h1>My Nice Component</h1>
{{yield (action "save")}}`

```
{{#my-nice as |saveAction| }}
 …
 <a onclick={{ action saveAction }}>Save</save>
{{/my-nice}}
```